# How do I install john the ripper 1.9 instead of 1.8

Tags: software-installation, kali

I need to use john the ripper for a project.
I install using:

```
$ sudo apt install john
```

which installs version `1.8`. I then try cracking a very simple file:

```
$ john --format=raw-MD5 passwordFoobarFile
```

To which I get this answer:

```
Unknown ciphertext format name requested
```

Which I don't understand. When I search for this issue, the only thing I can find is that my john probably a bad version. I try to search for how I could install a newer version, or update the one I have, but can't really find much.
Other tutorials usually just run `sudo apt install john`, and then get `1.9`

Is there anything I can do to avoid this error? or somehow I can get 1.9?

Comment: Kali Linux isn't a normal operating system. It is a tool designed for experts and if you don't know the answers to basic support question, you really shouldn't be using Kali Linux since it will only make your life harder. Use any GNU/Linux and you can do everything you can do on Kali Linux.  https://www.kali.org/docs//introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/   Please be aware; in https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, you'll note Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you pasted is explaining what is wrong:

```
Unknown ciphertext format name requested
```

The `format` you provided, `raw-md5`, is unknown to the application.

Based on [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/john.8.html), the `--format` option accepts only the following values: `DES`, `BSDI`, `MD5`, `BF`, `AFS`, `LM`.

If you do not include this option, the the tool will make a guess.